# SonataAdminBundle exports html instead of xls

Tags: excel, symfony, sonata-admin, xls, symfony-sonata

I use SonataAdminBundle version `2.2.x@dev` (commit `0d310108704c200f1542a00761ad3a884c24deb0`) and when I export data in xml format - got html content in `.xls` file. Other format works well.

Why it can be? Missed dependency on server or bug in particular version?

Comment: Checkout the route declarations `app/console debug:router` find the xml export route and see to what controller it's mapped.

Comment: @MihaiStancu format- GET parameter and it's not in route, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like sonanta has always done that. Xls are created by generated html compatible file.

The problem come from a recent office update which block html content for security reason. You should take a look at this for more information : [Excel refusing to open files](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3098898/microsoft-windows/excel-refusing-to-open-files-blame-the-kb-3115322-3115262-security-updates.html)

Comment: You are right! I deal with this problem with PHPExcel (override xls export)